# How to maintain transaction in Linq To Entites

Tags: c#, linq, transactions, linq-to-entities

Suppose I am inserting records in following Tables at the same time

Table 1

Table 2 

Table 3

Table 4

Table 5

Now What I want to do is, In-case of any exception or error occurs during insertion in Table 3 , then record which are inserted before that (eg. in Table 1 and Table 2) must be roll back...

How can I manage transaction like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, SaveChanges will execute in a transaction (see the [Remarks part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792.aspx) in the docs)

If you want more control over the transaction, you can wrap your savechanges block in a TransactionScope. SaveChanges will then pickup your ambient transaction and use that one.

This can be useful when you want a distributed transaction (for example with multiple contexts or if you use WCF).

As you mentioned that you use different models, you would use both ObjectContexts within one TransactionScope (and use [some logic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/01/11/savechanges-false.aspx) with AcceptAllChanges)

Your code would then look like:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()) 
{ 
    //Do something with context1 
    //Do something with context2


    //Save Changes but don't discard yet 
    context1.SaveChanges(false); 

    //Save Changes but don't discard yet 
    context2.SaveChanges(false);


    //if we get here things are looking good. 
    scope.Complete(); 

    //If we get here it is save to accept all changes. 
    context1.AcceptAllChanges(); 
    context2.AcceptAllChanges();
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the default behaviour of Entity Framework 4

The transaction is implicit .. as soon as you call savechanges any errors will trigger a rollback.

Comment: Can I handle it manually ? Actually PrimaryKey Of Table1 would be ForeignKey for Table2 and PK Of Table2 would be FK for Table3 and so on... So how will it work ?

Comment: @DotNetIsMyPower You need to associate them. Specify this associations as if the fields are already available. Table2.Prop = Table1.Prop; etc

Comment: But they are in different model. though let me try. @scartag Thanks buddy for quick reply